# WPF Image HESREST：0x88982F72

Tags: c#, wpf

This picture can't be displayed
Anything else will do.
Image URL: http://eyy250.com/132.jpg

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="http://eyy250.com/132.jpg"></Image>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Is it a corrupt file? If you open the file in paint and resave it, or e.g. run it through ImageMagick, will WPF open it then?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the Xaml, therefore the link is incorrect. You should either get a different link or download the image and add it to your project

Comment: Img Url  http://eyy250.com/132.jpg   Save locally as unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieve your scenario by setting **[CreateOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions?view=netframework-4.8)** as **IgnoreColorProfile** in BitMap as like below code.

```
        <Image Width="300" Height="300">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage CreateOptions="IgnoreColorProfile" UriSource="http://eyy250.com/132.jpg"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
```